# Why isn't NSUserDefaults syncing properly?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsuserdefaults

```
NSArray *arrFuelType = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Petrol", @"Diesel", @"LPG", @"CNG", nil];

NSUserDefaults *fuelTypeDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[fuelTypeDefaults setObject:arrFuelType forKey:@"fueltype"];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:TRUE forKey:@"fueltype"];

[fuelTypeDefaults synchronize];
```

I am doing this operation to save nsuserdefaults, but every time it stores "1".
I can't understand why is this storing value like this !!!
So what should I do ??

Comment: Heh, you are storing twice to the defaults. Last one means "1"

Comment: What do you mean, can you please explain ??

Comment: just change key name of your bool value..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you use different key like  :

```
NSUserDefaults *fuelTypeDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[fuelTypeDefaults setObject:arrFuelType forKey:@"fueltype_array"];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:TRUE forKey:@"fueltype_bool"];
```

retrieve this value:

```
 NSMutableArray *arr= [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]arrayForKey:@"fueltype_array"];
    bool *bol=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults ]boolForKey:@"fueltype_bool"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the same key. What you do is erasing the previous variable (so your array).

Comment: I am not overwriting values for same key, this operation is performed only when app runs for the first time

Answer (score 0):

You can't save two objects for same key.As you must need to take separate `KEY` for each Object.
You can check if the `Key` Exits for not if `objectForKey:` will return nil if key with name doesn't exist.

As your describe your result showing `1` because at last you put this statement

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:TRUE forKey:@"fueltype"];
```

So it retruning the `TRUE` value means `1` as  `0` means `false` and `1` means `true`.

Comment: `[fuelTypeDefaults setObject:arrFuelType forKey:@"fueltype"];`
First one with the name of `fueltype` And
`[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:TRUE forKey:@"fueltype"];` Second one with the same name of `fueltype`. so try another name. review updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are storing different values for same key. You need to use different key names.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use different keys,

```
NSArray *arrFuelType = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Petrol", @"Diesel", @"LPG", @"CNG", nil];

NSUserDefaults *fuelTypeDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[fuelTypeDefaults setObject:arrFuelType forKey:@"fueltype"];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:TRUE forKey:@"boolKey"];

[fuelTypeDefaults synchronize];
```